# How to notify user at specific event?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to notify user of mobile as particular event take place,Using notification bar icon.
Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: Notify how? With a popup? (maybe a toast?)

Comment: You mean this one? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this method where you required.its worked for me properly.
Hope it will solve your problem.

```
private void notification(Context c) 
{
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EfficientAdapter1 e1=new EfficientAdapter1(c);
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) e1.no(ns);

    //int icon = R.drawable.xyz;//your image
    CharSequence tickerText = "ticker text";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, Text, when);

    Context context = c;
    CharSequence contentTitle = "your title";
    CharSequence contentText = " your text";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ViewAllSMS.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    final int HELLO_ID = 1;

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android NotificationManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)
Refer the app dev guide example - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

After setting the required properties and calling the notify method, the status bar would show up the notification which you require.

Omkar Ghaisas

Answer (score 1):

You can always go for [pop ups](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). they are neat and gives you chance to notify the user. Other wise you can use [toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) also. Just the problem in toast is that it appears for some time and then disappears, so if somehow user misses that toast he may never know about toast. or say notification. You can see example [here](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-toasts-and-alerts/)